# MacOS: Commit TextField when clicked outside

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

From a UX point, the goal is to commit the input when people click anywhere outside the `TextField`.

For example, if the input is for renaming an item, then when clicked outside, we store the input as the new item name, and replace the `TextField` with a `Text` to show the new item name.

I assume it is an expected standard behavior, but please let me know if it is against Apple's MacOS standards.

Is there a standard / conventional way to achieve it with SwiftUI, or with some AppKit workaround?

As I see, `onCommit` is only triggered when we hit the Return key, not when we click outside the `TextField`. So what I think what I need to figure out is how to detect clicking outside.

What I considered:

1. Some built-in view modifier on the `TextField` which activates this behavior, but I couldn't find any.
2. Detect focus loss or `editingChanged` of the `TextField`, but by default, when we click on the background / a button / a text, the `TextField` doesn't lose focus, nor is the `editingChanged` event triggered.
3. If the `TextField` is focused, add an overlay on the ContentView with an `onTapGesture` modifier, but then it would take two taps to trigger a button when a TextField is focused.
4. Add an `onTapGesture` modifier on the ContentView, which calls a `focusOut` method, but it doesn't receive the event when people tap on a child view that also has an `onTapGesture` on it.
5. Improving on 4, also call `focusOut` from the `onTapGesture` callback of all child views. So far this is the only viable option I see, but I'm not sure it is a good pattern to put extra code in all `onTapGesture`s, just in order to customize `TextField` behavior.

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct app: App {
    @State private var inputText: String = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Color.secondary.onTapGesture { print("Background tapped") }
                VStack {
                    Text("Some label")
                    Button("Some button") { print("Button clicked") }
                    TextField(
                        "Item rename input",
                        text: $inputText,
                        onCommit: { print("Item rename commit") }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58988238/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Not entirely. As I understand, your code answers how to programatically take focus from the TextField. But my question is also about when/where to call your code - please see options 3-5 which I listed.