# Remove default Focus on TextField SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, focus

I'm creating a menu bar app on macos. I have one `TextField` in a form, and upon launching the app, this `TextField` is automatically focused on.

These are my attempts:

1. I tried using `@FocusState`, `defaultFocus` but the `TextField` is still focused on automatically (it stays focused even when I click outside the `TextField`).
2. I also tried using `.prefersDefaultFocus(false, in: formNamespace)` on the `TextField` but it didn't work.
3. I also tried disabling focus altogether by doing `.focusable(false)` on the `TextField`. This prevents the `TextField` from automatically being focused on when the app is launched. But once it is clicked on, the focus doesn't go away.

```swift
// Code for attempt 1

struct MyView: view {
  @State private var newEntry: String = ""
  @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool?

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      HStack {
        TextField("", text: $newEntry, prompt: Text("Add new entry"))
          .focused($isFocused, equals: true)
        
        // ...

        Button("Add") {
          // ...
          isFocused = false
        }
      }
    }
    .onSubmit {
      // ...
      isFocused = false
    }
    .defaultFocus($isFocused, false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How can I remove Textfield focus when I press return or click outside Textfield? (SwiftUI, MacOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987542/how-can-i-remove-textfield-focus-when-i-press-return-or-click-outside-textfield)

```
.onAppear {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
          NSApp.keyWindow?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
     }
 }
```